# PHP select categories and count number

Tags: php, mysql, sql, categories

Table categories:

```
id, name,    
-------------
1   category1
2   category2
3   category3
4   category4
```

Table posts:

```
id, category, title
--------------------
1   1, 3      title1
2   4, 2      title2
3   1, 4      title3
```

I would like to have a show categories and counter posts in this category. In the category column in the table posts I IDs of categories, which are separated by ', '. How to do that is searched when category = category ID and show counter with a minimum of SQL queries.

Comment: Fix your data structure to have a proper junction table with one row per post and category.

Comment: Don't use csv, especially if you want to search. If you need multiple values for a row, create a new table with rows for the `id` and each `category`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should fix your data structure to have one row per post and category.  A comma-separated list is *not* a SQLish way to store data for many reasons.  You should change this to a junction table.

Here are some reasons why:

- Numbers should be stored as numbers and not strings.
- Foreign key relationships should be properly defined, and you can't do that with a string to a number.
- An attribute should contain *one* value.
- MySQL doesn't have very good support for string processing functions.
- Queries using the column cannot be optimized using indexes.

You should have a table called `PostCategories` for this information.

Sometimes, we are stuck with other peoples bad design decisions.  If so, you can use a query such as:

```
select c.id, count(*)
from posts p join
     categories c
     on find_in_set(c.id, replace(p.category)) > 0
group by c.id;
```

Comment: A lot of people are surprisingly ignorant of the [Zero, One or Infinity Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule).